# NAvigation bar not appear

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to make my `Navigationbar`Clear color. So I tried like this in my `ViewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage=[UIImage new];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title=[lan GetConvertedLanguageString:@"My Profile"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];



self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backarrow"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(revealToggle :)];
[self.navigationController navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

But nothing visible in my view controller. Whats wrong with this code? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot

[image]

Code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage=[UIImage new];
self.navigationItem.title = @"1234";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]; 
[self.navigationController navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

So,I guess,your background of View is White,so you cannot see  white text.

Note

navigationBar.titleTextAttributes

> Display attributes for the bar’s title text.

navigationBar.tintColor

> The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Check this image]
Pick up navigation controller scene and then pickup navigationbar (see in pic) after that set the clear color from showutilites>attribute insepecter also you can change title color from here